# N-Mosfet Rds Value Question and Use for Bidirectional Logic Coversion Purpose

Tags: mosfet

I was using BSS138 for Bidirectional logic conversion from 5v to 3.3v.

- Rds(on) 3.5ohm at VGS=10v,
- Rds(on) 6ohm at VGS=4.5v

I found smaller package with same price SSM3K59CTB and i need small package its values are:

- RDS(ON) = 250 mΩ (typ.) (@VGS = 1.8 V, ID = 0.2 A)
- RDS(ON) = 210 mΩ (typ.) (@VGS = 2.5 V, ID = 0.5 A)
- RDS(ON) = 185 mΩ (typ.) (@VGS = 4.5 V, ID = 1.0 A)
- RDS(ON) = 175 mΩ (typ.) (@VGS = 8.0 V, ID = 1.0 A)

Other values are smilar or better like threshold,continuous current,Vds etc.

**Can i use this SSM3K59CTB instead of BSS138 since i dont know what is this Rds affecting**. I know it is too much for logic conversion but its package is smallest i could found.

[image]

Comment: MAke SURE you understand how this converter works in both directions and the affect of the FET Vgsth and Vgs vs Rdson in general. While the circuit is "simple enough" it is dependant on the FET meeting certain limits. A "better" FET may not work.

Comment: @Russell McMahon I understand how it works. Is the switching time depend on the capacitance or turn on off time of mosfet.

Answer (score 1):

Rds is the resistance between the drain and source of the transistor. This resistance causes power losses with high currents, but in your case it sounds like you are not using the transistor to drive high currents so Rds has little effect to your system, thus you could use any one of your MOSFETs. Usually smaller the Rds, the better.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you will connect the gate to the 5V signal, the source to GND, and the drain to the 3V3 signal with a pullup?

Yes, it should work, but the gate capacitance will make it a bit slow. It is up to you to decide if this is a problem.

However, you could also use a 74LVC1G04 single gate, which works at 3V3, has 5.5V tolerant inputs, tiny package, and will be much faster if you need it. You can also use the non-inverting version. If you have several lines to translate, remember all LVC logic chips have 5.5V tolerant inputs.

If you need slow and simple, you could also use just a resistor. It should be a high enough value that the receiver chip's protection diodes act as a voltage limiter without suffering.

Comment: I added the picture showing connections. I am also using with speed around 1 mhz would it be okay

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed your need for *bidirectional* translation (the solutions I posted won't work for bidirectional translation). In this schematic, the higher capacitance of your new FET might not interact well with your high value pullups. I suggest running a SPICE sim if you can find a model for the new one (or a model for a close relative).

Comment: Thanks. If it is one directional can voltage divider 2 resistor would be fast enough. For example max what freq. would be okay with 2 resistors as voltage divider

Comment: @snrIcmn, if you want to use a resistor divider for logic down-conversion, the maximum resistor values depend on the load capacitance.

Comment: Yes, check input capacitance at receiving side. If you need low power, a little 74LVC chip will probably consume less than a resistor divider, though.